# Why does my .on() get called several times on one click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a simple script to remove checkboxes from the DOM when they are clicked. I have to have this in an a loop because I am polling some data at a set interval. This causes some weird issues with this script:

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZWXjk/)

HTML:

```
<label class="delete">
    <input type="checkbox" checked="" id="checkdelete" name="261"> 
</label>
    <label class="delete">
    <input type="checkbox" checked="" id="checkdelete" name="261"> 
</label>
        <label class="delete">
    <input type="checkbox" checked="" id="checkdelete" name="261"> 
</label>
```

Javascript:

```
var queueInterval = setInterval(function() {
    $('input#checkdelete').on('change', function(){
        console.log($(this).attr('name'));
      $(this).parent('.delete').remove();  
    });  
}, 1000);
```

As you can see if you click on a checkbox it outputs a seemingly random amount of calls to the console. This is bad because I'm actually doing to do a .post() after the checkbox is clicked, and it's getting called a bunch of times per click.

When it is outside of the loop there is no problem. Also if I give each checkbox a unique ID it doesn't behave like this, but then all of the checks don't work.

Any help here?

Comment: Probably because you have multiple elements with the same ID.   Don't do that.  Find another way to select the checkboxes.

Comment: because you are adding  a new handler in every second

Comment: How can I give each element a unique ID, but still have the function work?

Comment: what is the purpose of the `setInterval()`

Comment: @ArunPJohny doesn't the OP also remove the parent() so the onclick doesn't repeat? I think it's to do with the multiple ids

Comment: @jasonscript No, it's not because of multiple IDs. When you have multiple IDs, selectors just match the first one and ignore the duplicates.

Comment: @jasonscript yes the OP removed the clicked item but to the rest of the elements OP is added a new handler

Comment: may be http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9drXy/1/ ? - also note that ID has to be unique so use a class to group those elements together

Comment: @ArunPJohny its in an interval because in the actual script I am polling some data from the server to keep it current. It pulls in an unordered list of records, and each <li> has up to 5 of these checkboxes

Comment: @dmarzio then look at the fiddle I posted to see how to register handlers for dynamically added elements

Comment: @ArunPJohny Your script is exactly what I needed. I put your changes into my code, and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is, you are adding a change handler inside a `setInterval()` loop, it will add a new change handler to all the existing checkboxes every second. Thus it will bind multiple change handler to the checkboxes, so when a checkbox state is changed each of those handlers will get called.

The solution here is to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to add support for dynamically added elements like

```
var queueInterval = setInterval(function () {
    //do what ever else you want to do here
}, 1000);

//use checkdelete as a class not as an id because ID of an element must be unique
$(document).on('change', '.checkdelete', function () {
    console.log($(this).attr('name'));
    $(this).parent('.delete').remove();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9drXy/)

Answer (score 1):

Every second you'll be applying the same event handler to **ALL** the checkboxes that are on the screen, so every second you'll be applying some number of event handlers based on the checkboxes on the screen. Also, not to mention, using the #id selector is supposed to be unique. Use a class handler for items that appear multiple times on a page.

check this code out here: http://jsfiddle.net/notsoluckycharm/ZWXjk/1/

It separates your concerns a lot more cleanly. You would have a container that you append your labels/checkboxes too, and the container would handle the event delegation.

```
$('div').on('change', 'input', function(){
    $(this).parent('.delete').remove(); 
});
var queueInterval = setInterval(function() {
   $(".container").append('<label class="delete"> \
    <input type="checkbox" checked="" id="checkdelete" name="261">\
   </label>');
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

As people were saying in the comments, you should only have one element with the same ID. If you change the ID to a class this is much better style. The reason it keeps sending the input is because of the setInterval(). The number of times it sends it is the number of seconds between your clicks. I modified your fiddle and you can see the result here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZWXjk/2/

```
$('input.checkdelete').on('change', function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('name'));
    $(this).parent('.delete').remove();  
});
```